# questions about SQL in generated (ADO.NET) DataAdapter (UpdateCommand)

Tags: c#, ado.net, dataset

This following is from a generated data adapter:

```
this._adapter.UpdateCommand.CommandText = @"
    UPDATE [dbo].[Currency2] SET [cid1] = @cid1, [cid2] = @cid2, [m] = @m 
    WHERE (([id] = @Original_id) 
    AND ([cid1] = @Original_cid1) 
    AND ([cid2] = @Original_cid2) 
    AND ([m] = @Original_m));

    SELECT id, cid1, cid2, m 
    FROM Currency2 
    WHERE (cid1 = @cid1) AND (cid2 = @cid2) AND (id = @id)";
```

1. Is the where clause implementing optimistic concurrency per its formal definition?
2. My best guess is that the purpose of the SELECT is to return number of updated rows, but then why doesn't it use COUNT(*)?

Update: Here is the generated UPDATE code, which gave me the ideas about the SELECT in (2).

```
public virtual int Update(int cid1, int cid2, decimal m, int Original_id, int Original_cid1, int Original_cid2, decimal Original_m, int id) {
    this.Adapter.UpdateCommand.Parameters[0].Value = ((int)(cid1));
    this.Adapter.UpdateCommand.Parameters[1].Value = ((int)(cid2));
    this.Adapter.UpdateCommand.Parameters[2].Value = ((decimal)(m));
    this.Adapter.UpdateCommand.Parameters[3].Value = ((int)(Original_id));
    this.Adapter.UpdateCommand.Parameters[4].Value = ((int)(Original_cid1));
    this.Adapter.UpdateCommand.Parameters[5].Value = ((int)(Original_cid2));
    this.Adapter.UpdateCommand.Parameters[6].Value = ((decimal)(Original_m));
    this.Adapter.UpdateCommand.Parameters[7].Value = ((int)(id));
    global::System.Data.ConnectionState previousConnectionState = this.Adapter.UpdateCommand.Connection.State;
    if (((this.Adapter.UpdateCommand.Connection.State & global::System.Data.ConnectionState.Open) 
        != global::System.Data.ConnectionState.Open)) {
    this.Adapter.UpdateCommand.Connection.Open();
    }
    try {
    int returnValue = this.Adapter.UpdateCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
    return returnValue;
    }
    finally {
    if ((previousConnectionState == global::System.Data.ConnectionState.Closed)) {
        this.Adapter.UpdateCommand.Connection.Close();
    }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

What that query does is, returns the updated record back to the application for future use, so that you have updated object in memory, instead of it's state before update. It basically is `UPDATE xxx WHERE ID=@ID` and `SELECT xxx FROM xxx WHERE ID=@ID` commands in one roundtrip.

Comment: I added the code from the generated update, which calls ExecuteNonQuery... the SQL isn't referenced anywhere else i can see...

Answer (score 1):

> Is the where clause implementing
>   optimistic concurrency per its formal
>   definition?

Sort of.  It's checking every single column to see if anyone has changed any of them.  If the record HAS changed, it's not updated.

However, one definition (from Wikipedia) says the transaction is rolled back if the record has changed.  That isn't happening here.